# Displaying the sum of a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this: `id | item_name | price`

I have a loop that displays all items with the grand total at the bottom.

```
$total_price = 0;

foreach($items as $item)
{
    echo $item->item_name;
    echo $item->price;

    $total_price += $item->price;
}

echo $total_price;
```

However, what I need is to display the `$total_price` at the TOP of the page, before I loop through all the items.

Is it better to loop through the `foreach` again at the top of the page to calculate the total price, or should I be making a separate database call that only returns the total price?

Comment: To add to that, you can sum it in the SAME query, you don't need to make a second database call.

Comment: I would submit that it's reasonable to run two queries - one for the data, and one for the total. I would not iterate the collection twice and sum it up yourself, though. You could sum it up in one loop and defer the output (see newage's answer.)

Comment: By your query I meant the only one he is doing

Comment: If you use 2 loops you will loose processor time. If you will use @newage answer, you will loose RAM. Ideally, you should calculate that in query that gives you the data. But this looks like overoptimizing, you won't feel big difference in small list on regular project. And if it would be the highload, you probably knew the answer already:-)

Comment: @IanP, you don't have to run 2 queries, one is usually enough to get both data and sum of some column.

Comment: I am familiar with `SUM()` but how would I return all the results along with the total of all results in a single call? I always thought it was one or the other.

Comment: @SergeKuharev only those people talk about ram who doesnt know how to add one more RAM to motherboard :) and untill huge traffic it really wont make much effect as you said :)

Comment: But doesn't `SUM()` only return a single row, unless you specify a `group by`? And even then, it adds the sum to each row, so then how do you display the total sum of everything in the same call?

Comment: @Staysee, SUM() will return same result for each row. You just try it :-)

Comment: @Staysee one way to to have data and sum in a single query but this query will produce an extra raw at the end also this query needs group by with auto increment to full fill sum()'s requirement in  php loop you need to skip the last row,and for total you need to get the last row only [**see demo here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06762/4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple and fast decision

```
$total_price = 0;
$print = '';
foreach($items as $item)
{
    $print .= $item->item_name;
    $print .= $item->price;

    $total_price += $item->price;
}

echo $total_price;
echo $print;
```

If you can get sum from SQL base it will be more best solution. In MySQL use function `SUM()`

Example:

`SELECT SUM(price) AS total FROM ...`

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. This is a reasonable solution.

Comment: This one does answers the question i guess due lack of description he is getting downvotes

Comment: I agree with the "due lack of description" part of M Khalid Junaid's comment!!

Comment: @NullPoiиteя if you see the loop code provided by OP the output of that loop is also a single string for the browser ,although new age has shown how the loop output can be use by appending values if OP is curious regarding  mixing values then he should first update his question with original output he wants, also this a simple example you can use arrays/variables for different type of values in different arrays/variables

Comment: ohh i just thought he wants some of price which actually makes sense ... removing my comments ...and sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons why you should never mix php code and direct output. I would suggest you look into one of the template engines for php.

Unless you are writing php-cli do all the operations before you start to output. This will increase the flexibility of your code a lot.

[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/%20Smarty) is one of my favourite tempelate engines, easy to setup and with powerfull features, but that's my opinion.

Comment: this answer had really nothing to do with question ... possible comment and its fine to mix php code with output if you know what you are doing

Comment: Well he asked how to change the order of the output.. and a template will do it without the need to run the code twice or use placeholder variables.

Comment: i am completely agree with you but telling someone use this X thing which takes Y amount of time to learn isnt best until only choice ...

Comment: for a quick and dirty solution true, but the person could be taught to think about his/her application design and not just up-down coding aswell as solve the "problem"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need use MySQL query like this:

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM your_table
```